# Create a System performance Windows 10 App (for store)

Tags: c#, c++, windows-store-apps

I'm tasked with a need to migrate an application I previously created as a Windows service in .NET to an application which can be added to the windows store. (Which I understand must use the UWP format, but please correct me if that's wrong.)

My service collected data about CPU, Memory, Network data and uptime and then could ship it off via a call to my external RESTful API.

Moving to the UWP format, all of my previous code becomes invalid.  (I don't have access to System.Diagnostics.Performance counter, for instance.)

I've been looking at all options, including using C++ to get at Native Calls, but that doesn't seem to help.

It dawned on me that the performance tab in task manager is gathering exactly the data I need.  So my root question is, how can I get at this type of data using an application which can be built for the windows store?

[Sample of the Performance Tab in W10 Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIqHj.png)

TIA,
Jeremy

Comment: I think you should make an attempt to start and do some research online.  Once you have something - post it.  This way we have something to look at and help you with.  Otherwise someone would just be doing it for you :)

Comment: [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsstore/archive/2012/06/08/listing-your-desktop-app-in-the-store.aspx) from 2012 talks about the process of submitting desktop apps to the Windows 8 store. All of this may have changed since then, but it's worth checking.

Comment: It's odd, [System.Diagnostics namespaces for UWP apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185506.aspx) says "*System.Diagnostics and its child namespaces (System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis, System.Diagnostics.Contracts, and System.Diagnostics.Tracing) contain types that enable you to interact with system processes, event logs, and **performance counters**.*" (bold mine), but I can't find anywhere where to get them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can not collect the diagnostics you need with uwp apis